# my search icon is not showing up when it becomes responsive

Tags: css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .top-navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .search-box {
        margin: 10px 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    .search-box input {
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }

    .search-box .fas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 10px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .user-actions {
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .user-actions a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .user-actions a i {
        margin-right: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .user-actions a span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

here is my header, where the search icon is displayed when its not responsive

[image]

here is my header, where search icon is not showing when its responsive

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please try to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) otherwise we will have a hard time helping you.